# keybd_event() not working in ACTIVEX module with IE PROTECTED MODE

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, internet-explorer, activex

keybd_event() is not working in ACTIVEX module with PROTECTED MODE - I am using activex that simulates keypress but it simply does nothing with new IE8.

```
  keybd_event(VK_SPACE, MapVirtualKey(VK_SPACE, 0), 0, 0);
  keybd_event(VK_SPACE, MapVirtualKey(VK_SPACE, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

is there a trick to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. To offer improved security, IE8 now hosts tabs and add-ons loaded in [separate processes with limited permissions](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx). Much like Chrome does and the new FireFox 4 will do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a BHO. It works initially, then it stops, and also sometimes crashes the iexplore.exe tab instance.

I have found that IE8 version of ieframe.dll seems to be using the [Detours library](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to hook several Windows APIs, including SendInput & keybd_event.